# Parameter passed without explicitly stating javascript Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So this example chrome extension calls a selector for media streams and then the `gotStream(stream)` clearly is looking for a parameter of a mediaObject. However, when the `gotStream` function is passed in as the second parameter to `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` no parameter is passed in. It merely remains states the function name.

Here is the code

```
function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Received local stream");
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localstream = stream;
  stream.onended = function() { console.log("Ended"); };
}

function getUserMediaError() {
  console.log("getUserMedia() failed.");
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
  if (!id) {
    console.log("Access rejected.");
    return;
  }
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
      audio:false,
      video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                            chromeMediaSourceId: id } }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
}
```

I've seen these kinds of calls before and I just don't get how they work, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an error of some sorts, or you just don't understand how that works?

`navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` [expects 3 arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia). One for configuration data, one for a function to call on success (a success *callback*) and one to call on error.

Note that it expects a *function*. This code passes a reference to the function by name; it will be called with the appropriate parameter (from within `webkitGetUserMedia`).

Consider this code, it works in the same manner:

```js
function hello(subject) {
  alert("Hello, " + subject + "!");
}

function passWorldTo(callback) {
  callback("world");  
}

passWorldTo(hello);
```

Comment: I understand how the call back works and that it expects a function the issue I am having trouble with is one of the parameters--a function-- specifically the second parameter passed in is gotStream. It passes in just the word of the function gotStream with no parameters. However gotStream expects parameter stream--gotStream(stream)-- and it uses this stream and it is a valid mediaObject. I am wondering how did it pass gotStream without any parameters did gotStream successfully receive a stream parameter. I've seen this is countless times in javascript and it must be some simple truth I lack.

Comment: Look _closely_ at my code. I also pass `hello` to `passWorldTo` without the word `"world"`, and yet it is called with the correct parameter. The point is, you pass the function `gotStream` to `webkitGetUserMedia`, and the parameter is generated inside that function.

Comment: You've just incepted my brain. Thank you very much for your patience!